# Video-player does not work in Ubuntu

Tags: video-player

I'm a Ubuntu newbie running 14.04 "Trusty Tahr" on a Dell laptop. Everything seems to work well so far, except for online movies, which don't play at all. (I don't yet have any DVD discs of movies.) I can only play Youtube. No LCV or Totem app appears. Yet I did the command for LCV, and Terminal seemed to accept it.The video icon linked to Dashboard remains a stubborn black/grey picture of a film director's clapboard. The only data beneath it reads "Stopped 00:00". Is there a simple Ubuntu-compatible movie that I can test start, and how would I go about it? I'm willing to subscribe to a movies account.

Tartanchap

Comment: What are you trying to watch movies on? Netflix?

Comment: Virtually all video types can be played in Ubuntu. Did you think to install ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Comment: Thank you @ElefantPhace. I haven't tried Netflix yet on Ubuntu. I was looking for individual films to start with but see now that the best films are rented/sold by the big firms. However, I saw a fantastic 1960s film last night in German on Youtube and will definitely use Youtube again for old German movies.

Comment: Thank you @Elder Greek. I did try that installation. I think my difficulty was that I was unable to find decent films not held by the big monopolies. There must be some out there. Would be useful if Ubuntu could publish a list of film sources for beginners. But I guess that might contravene principles about not advertising sources of movies.

Comment: Let's see if we can clarify your question a bit. You are looking for a subscription source for movies that you can use under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the flashplugin.

Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and type the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: Thank you. I have just done that according to your instruction. Terminal accepted the command. Please forgive my inexperience. I don't know what to do next. I'm willing to rent an on-line movie but don't know how I would link it to the downloaded video player or flash plugin.

Comment: I do not know what is the program you use to rent movies, but try to install ubuntu-restricted-extras:
    sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Comment: Thank you @Patterson. Followed that advice. It turns out my difficulty was in finding a suitable program for me to rent movies, as I don't like oligopolies. Now I think I'll stick with free movies until I run out of decent ones. I know where to find some now. And I might ask the British Film Institute for sources too.